# Regular Expression to Remove Subdomains from Domain List

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of domains and subdomains stored in a .txt file (I'm using Windows XP).

The format of the domains  is this:

> somesite1.com
>
> sub1.somesite1.com
>
> sub2.somesite1.com
>
> somesite2.com
>
> sub1.somesite2.com
>
> sub2.somesite2.com
>
> somesite3.com
>
> sub1.somesite3.com
>
> sub2.somesite3.com

I use notepad++, and I need to use regular expressions

Anyway, I don't know what to put in the find & replace boxes so it can go through the contents of the file and leave me with only the root domains. If done properly, it would turn the above example list into this:

> somesite1.com
>
> somesite2.com
>
> somesite3.com

Can somebody help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but the answers provided didn't work for me. You need a negative lookahead. The correct regex is:

```
^\w*\.(?!\w+\s*\n)
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for subdomain containing `-`, for example `my-quest.game.com`

Comment: Replacing `-` was not part of the question. However, you can use`^[\w|-]*\.(?![\w|-]+\s*\n)` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Find what: `[^\r\n]+\.[^.\r\n]+\.[^.\r\n]+[\r\n]+`
Replace with: `empty_string`

with regular expression checked and dot match line-feed NOT checked

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the **Mark** tab of the Notepad++ **Find** dialogue. Enter the regular expression `^\w+\.\w+\.\w+$`, make sure that **Bookmark line** is selected, then click **Mark all**. Next, use Menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Remove bookmarked lines**. These will remove all entries having with three "words" separated by two dots. It will leave all other lines in place.

An alternative is to mark all lines matching the regular expression `^\w+\.\w+$` and use the **Remove unmarked lines** menu entry. This I do not recommend as it will remove all lines with an unexpected format as well as the lines for subdomains.

Another method would use the **Replace** tab of the Notepad++ **Find** dialogue.  Enter the regular expression `^\w+\.\w+\.\w+\r\n` in the **Find what** field, and leave the **Replace with** field empty. The `\r\n` part of this expression may need some adjustment to account for the line endings set on the file.